# Suggested materials for monitor stand?

Tags: wooden-furniture

I have a 27" iMac and a second 30" display, and since I'm fairly tall I need them raised off the desk by about 20cm / 8".

What is a good building material/design to build such a stand? I'm looking for a clean/simple look - probably timber painted black.

I'm fairly capable (my dad is a carpenter and I've worked as his off-sider from time to time) but not very experienced and want to keep the budget low.

It needs to be around 1200mm by 350mm and strong enough to hold 30kg/65lb securely.

Comment: My 24" monitors sit on top of old phone books! lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I bought a sheet of Melamine and some big chunky pieces of timber that were available on special. I painted the timber black, put some self-adhesive rubber feet on and and attached to the melamine with L brackets.

Note the original plan was to have them raised by ~20cm. I didn't end up doing that.

I'm quite happy with the result.

[image: the result]

Answer (score 1):

You could build a simple box out of [medium-density fiberboard (MDF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-density_fibreboard).

[image: Simple Box]
[image: Simple Box (Exploded)]

If you really want to get fancy, you could build drawers into the front.

[image: Box with Drawers]

---

You could buy a piece of melamine shelf, a 4x4, and some L-brackets. And build a shelf like this.

[image: Monitor Stand]
[image: Monitor Stand Exploded]

Answer (score 0):

Trestle styles are strong and scalable to a tall version.

Pine for the understructure, perhaps a laminate for the top.